# My List View application is crashing again and again

Tags: android

I am a beginner in this android development world. I was using ListView, but the app crashes on the emulator, saying some exception given below. Can someone please help me, in making this app work

**My java code is :**

```
ListView listView;
String [] arr= {"list1", "List2", "List3"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    ArrayAdapter <String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
    listView.setAdapter(ad);

}
```

**My XML code is :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/ListView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**My Logcat shows various exceptions, please see and help me out:**

```
06/29 18:31:21: Launching 'app' on Harshs Phone.
Install successfully finished in 2 s 886 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.listviewapp/com.example.listviewapp.MainActivity" -a 
android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 12599 on device 'Harshs_Phone [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in 
the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.listviewapp, PID: 12599
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.listviewapp/com.example.listviewapp.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast 
to android.widget.ListView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
    at com.example.listviewapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Thank You (in advance).........................

Comment: android:id="@+id/ListView" set this id for list view,not for ConstraintLayout in your xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You** gave your `ContraintLayout` ID as `android:id="@+id/ListView"`.

**BUT** If you see line `ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.ListView);`, you are using/casting `ContraintLayout` as `ListView`. You put ID in wrong component.

**Solution**

1. Delete `android:id="@+id/ListView"` in `ContraintLayout`
2. Add `android:id="@+id/ListView"` in `ListView`.

Thanks.

Comment: @HarshGaur Sure no problem